# Core Data fetching with objectID

Tags: swift, core-data

I have 2 entities in my data model as the images below:

Product:
[image: Product]

Attendance:
[image: Attendance]

I'm saving products with attendance relationship well! Now, I need to fetch the Products with a specific Attendance.objectID

I'm trying the following code:

```
func fetchProducts() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")
    let attendancePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "attendance.objectID == \(currAttendance.objectID)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = attendancePredicate
    
    print("Att = \(currAttendance.name!)")
    viewTypeSKU.hidden = true
    
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        products = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

I'm getting error: `'Unable to parse the format string "attendance.objectID ==`

Comment: What is currAttendance? Where are you grabbing that from?

Comment: Try doing `NSPredicate(format: "attendance.objectID = %@", currAttendance.objectID)`

Comment: You could also setup an inverse so that you could just do `currAttendance.product` and be done with it.

Comment: Why are you trying to match object IDs in a predicate? That's almost never the right solution to any problem.

Answer (score 8):

Inside the fetch `SELF` is comparable to `NSManagedObjectID` and to the `NSManagedObject`. However you cannot do `.objectID` on the item being fetched. My theory is this is because when doing the `.` it is looking for attributes and/or relationships for the specific entity where `.objectID` is part of `NSManagedObject`. I could be wrong though.

However, if you just switched your NSPredicate to one of these it will work.

`NSPredicate(format: "attendance == %@", currAttendance.objectID)`

or

`NSPredicate(format: "attendance == %@", currAttendance)`

Comment: @Ula That's interesting I was always under the impression that = was the same as == in NSPredicates. Did you try both ways?

Comment: Frankly, not. I just assumed it should be double. I didn’t know it’d work both ways. But honestly I prefer it that way just to keep the good practice. Whatsoever, the addition of ‘.objectID’ was the thing that helped me so thanks!